# How to selecte the child shape in Visio(C#)

Tags: c#, shapes, visio

I'm trying to select the child shape, but It's impossible.
My code doesn't works only child shape.

```
var app = await FlipClass.GetVisioApplicationAsync();
var doc = app.ActiveDocument;
var page = app.ActivePage;

Visio.Selection selection = page.Application.ActiveWindow.Selection;
Debug.WriteLine(selection.Count);
```

For example, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPWWr.png)
In the following situations, output is 1. It works good.
However, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqIan.png)
In the following situations, output is 0. The child shape was not selected.

Please, help.

I want to access the child shape to obtain the attribute value.

Comment: Please read about [Select method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.selection.select), this article also contains [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.selection.select#example)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```cs
Visio.Selection selection = page.Application.ActiveWindow.Selection;
selection.IterationMode = 0;
Debug.WriteLine(selection.Count);
```

if it works then read about selection [IterationMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.selection.iterationmode) and selection [PrimaryItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.selection.primaryitem)